# XML Unicode Safe Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, encoding

I'm looking for a way to encode an XML document using the #&233; encoding.

Using this basic code

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\Temp\XmlDocBase.xml");
xmlDoc.Save(@"D:\Temp\XmlDocBaseCopy.xml");
```

my Xml document pass from:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tag1>
  <comment>entit&#233;</comment>
</Tag1>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tag1>
  <comment>entité</comment>
</Tag1>
```

Regards

Comment: The XML is valid in both cases. Any particular reason you want character entities instead of the actual characters?

Comment: It's to interact with a documentation generation tool (an add-on to OWL-protégé) and the software generate À@ style characters when the XML is in the second format. But you are right, both XML are valid XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force encoding that does not support all unicode characters (i.e. ASCII). As result writer will be forced to use entities.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<Tag1><comment>entit&#233;</comment></Tag1>");

    var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(
        @"c:\temp\o.xml",
        new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII });
    doc.Save(writer);
```

Results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?><Tag1><comment>entit&#xE9;</comment></Tag1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on a string.

```
return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("entité");
```

Returns `entit&#233;`

HttpUtility is part of System.Web.

Comment: In XML it's a character reference. And you cannot directly use that string in XML APIs because the `&` will be escaped another time then.