# How to fix the Unicode of xml file

Tags: c#, xml

my xml:

```
<title>1&#x2003;Introduction</title>
<p>Compositional models in distributional semantics combine word vectors to yield new compositional vectors that represent</p>
```

after I convert the XML using xdocument or xmldocument or xelement the Unicode will look like this.

[image: The unicode will look like this]

> this is my code to save the xml.

```
 XDocument xdocc = XDocument.Load(files);
 XElement xele = XElement.Load(files);
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.Load(files);

        xdocc.Save("will.xml");
        xele.Save("will2.xml");
        xmldoc.Save("will3.xml");
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: when i convert my xml and save it, the unicode of the original xml will become square.

Comment: You need to share the code which is converting the xml.

Comment: check the code i send tnxs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML Unicode Safe Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279315/xml-unicode-safe-encoding)

Comment: Looks like you have a formfeed character at the top of the page.  Probably from a Fortran application.  ASCII encoding will remove the character.  How did the string get created.

Comment: after i save the xml my Unicode :&#x002A; will become symbol:*, so i want my unicode will be same after i save